# Submit button not working unless change input

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form calculator, when customer submit the form(input.php), it will open another page display the results(output.php target _blank). However, when they want to use the same page(input.php) to get the result again, the submit button not working anymore, unless they change some value in the input field, and for the drop down menu, the submit button won't work, even you changed the drop down value.

Can someone please help me to fix the problems? thanks. I just want the button enabled all the time, here is the partially code from input.php.

```
<form name="form1" action="output.php" method="post" target="_blank">
<table id="distax" width="750">
<th colspan="6">F. Discount & Taxes</th>
<tr> 
    <td width="120"><b><input type="radio" name="discountmu" id="disc" value="-" />Discount (-)<br /> <input type="radio" name="discountmu" id="mu" value="+" />Markup (+)</b></td> 
    <td width="80">% <input type="text" name="discmuv" size="3" value="0"></td>
    <td width="120"><b>2. Tax Goods:</b></td>
    <td width="80">% <input type="text" name="txgood" size="3" value="0" onkeyup="data_change(this);"></td>
    <td width="120"><b>3. Tax Services:</b><br />(for items in G)</td> 
    <td width="*">% <input type="text" name="txservice" size="3" value="0" onkeyup="data_change(this);"></td>
</tr>
```

```
<table id="extra" width="750">
<th colspan="6">E. Extras</th>
<tr>
    <td width="170"><b>1. Extra railing (total):</b></td>
    <td width="70"><input type="text" name="extrail" size="2" value="0" onkeyup="data_change(this);">ft</td>
    <td width="110"><b>2. Custom Color: </b></td>
    <td width="*"><select size="1" value="<?=$_SESSION['name']?> " name="R4" id="R4" onchange="showme()">
        <option selected value="noSS">Sand Stone (Ral 1019)</option>
        <option value="noEW">Euro White (Ral 9010)</option>
        <option value="noQG">Quartz Grey (Ral 8014)</option>
        <option value="noJB">Java Brown (Ral 8014)</option>
        <option value="yes">Custom</option>
        </select>
        <input type="text" id="color1other" name="color1other" style=" position:relative;display:none;" Size=20 value="enter custom color here">
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td width="170"> <b>3. Height adjustment [ft // cm]:</b></td>
    <td width="*">
    <select size="1" name="D8">
        <option value="1.125">+2'6&quot; // +76cm</option>
        <option value="1.1">+2'0&quot; // +61cm</option>
        <option value="1.075">+1'6&quot; // +46cm</option>
        <option value="1.05">+1'0&quot; // +30cm</option>
        <option value="1.025">+0'6&quot; // +15cm</option>
        <option selected value="1">0</option>
        <option value="0.985">-0'6&quot; // -15cm</option>
        <option value="0.97">-1'0&quot; // -30cm</option>
        <option value="0.955">-1'6&quot; // -46cm</option>
        <option value="0.94">-2'0&quot; // -61cm</option>
        <option value="0.925">-2'6&quot; // -76cm</option>
        <option value="0.91">-3'0&quot; // -91cm</option>
      </select>
    </td>
        <td width="110"><b>4. Freight (Sea/Land/Air): </b></td>
        <td width="*">
        <input type="text" id="freight" name="freight" Size=12 value="0"><b>USD</b>
    </td>
</tr>
```

```
<input type="Submit" Value="Get your quote"> as
<input type="radio" value="detail" checked name="report">Dealer <input type="radio" name="report" value="short"> Client version in English
</form>
```

thanks for the reply, here is the code for the javascript, didn't see anything related to the submit button

```
//Date: 05/27/2009 Edited by EG

function reload(form)
{

var val=form.cat.options[form.cat.options.selectedIndex].value; 
var val3=document.form1.load.value;
//Date: 07/27/2009 Edited by EG
//self.location=self.location + '&cat=' + val + '&load=' + val3;
//self.location='webcalc_input.php?PHPSESSID=' + ssidjs + '&cat=' + val + '&load=' + val3;
self.location='webcalc_input.php?cat=' + val + '&load=' + val3;
}

function reload3(form)
{
var val=form.cat.options[form.cat.options.selectedIndex].value; 
var val2=form.subcat.options[form.subcat.options.selectedIndex].value; 
var val3=document.form1.load.value;
//Date: 07/27/2009 Edited by EG
self.location= 'webcalc_input.php?cat=' + val + '&cat3=' + val2 + '&load=' + val3;
//self.location='webcalc_input.php?PHPSESSID=' + ssidjs + '&cat=' + val + '&cat3=' + val2 + '&load=' + val3;
}

function data_change(field) {
    var check = true;
    var value = field.value; //get characters
    //check that all characters are digits, ., -, or ""
    for (var i = 0; i < field.value.length; ++i) {
        var new_key = value.charAt(i); //cycle through characters
        if (((new_key < "0") || (new_key > "9")) && !(new_key == "") && (new_key != ".")) { //Included . to enable decimal entry
            check = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    //apply appropriate colour based on value
    if (!check) {
        field.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
    else {
        field.style.backgroundColor = "white";
    }
}

function validateEmpty(fld) {
    var error = "";
    if (fld.value.length == 0) {
        fld.style.background = 'Yellow';
        error = "The required field has not been filled in.\n"
    } else {
        fld.style.background = 'White';
    }
    return error;
}
```

Comment: Please post all the relevant javascript code.  You've only shown PHP/HTML

Answer (score 0):

The text input contains a javascript function which you don't show in your code called `data_change()`. If I understand the question, its likely that that function is disabling the submit button and enabling it when the text changes.  This is only an assumption without seeing your javascript code.

`enter code here`

Find the definition of the `data_change()` function and look for something relating to the submit button and comment it out.

You may remove the `onkeyup="data_change(this);"` from the `<input>` tag, but that could break other functionality!